# I have problem with inputing two variables in a single line

Tags: python-3.4

I was solving uri problem #1015 and get runtime error
the problem is I need to input 2 numbers in one line but how I can do this with input than scans the whole line?

## here is my code:

```
import math
x1 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())

distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2-y1) ** 2)
print("%.4f" % distance)
```

Comment: x1, y1 = map(float, input().split())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider taking the input line, splitting it, validating that you've got the right number and type of values, and than storing it.

```
accepted_values = False
vals = []

while not accepted_values:

    inp = input("Please input four numbers: ")
    splt = inp.split()

    if len(splt) != 4:
        print("Please input exactly 4 numbers, separated by spaces")
        continue

    try:
        vals = [float(s) for s in splt]
        accepted_values = True
    except ValueError:
        print("Some or all values couldn't be converted to string")

x1, y1, x2, y2 = vals
```